# Book ID: YA novel about siblings trying to rescue father

Tags: story-identification

Ok, I read this one a LONG time ago and have been looking for it ever since. It was in my elementary school library.

What I recall:
-brother and sister live with their mom on a plain at the foot of the mountains, there is a mountain pass that leads to a magical land, guarded by soldiers
-their dad snuck through the pass and hasn't been seen since so they decide to go and rescue him

I honestly don't recall a lot of the story itself except that there is a witch in a tower who captures the sister, the boy tames a "sun horse", they ultimately succeed.

Hopefully this is enough to spark someone's memory!

Comment: How long ago did you read this? A specific time period could be helpful.

Comment: Could it be [The Sun Horse](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1711237.The_Sun_Horse)? Seems unlikely (not brother and sister, etc), but there is a witch, a sun horse, a boy and a girl, and of course a missing father. Also mountains.

Comment: It could be--I read this a good 20 years ago, so my memory is very shaky on it. I am Canadian so it's probable this was the book!

Comment: OK, I'll post it as an answer later today. Stay around so you can look at it!

Answer (score 4):

### This could be *[The Sun Horse](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjVqIvsjvvMAhUm9IMKHTi0BuoQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.goodreads.com%2Fbook%2Fshow%2F1711237.The_Sun_Horse&usg=AFQjCNGC0B0_5daXB48woZBwGrOFkgo-1A&sig2=0RsNGFfZniy9746jBZlzsw)*

[image]

This book, written by Catherine Anthony Clark, was published in Canada in 1951. That makes two points in its favor:

- Published a long time ago
- The OP is Canadian and read it in elementary school, so probably in Canada

From Goodreads:

> Set in the province of British Columbia, Canada, the protagonist is an
>   orphaned boy, Mark, sent to live with his aunt and uncle. In his new
>   school, **he befriends a girl named Giselle**. **Her father has mysteriously
>   gone missing**, following a hunting trip during which Giselle suspects
>   that he was trying to capture **the beautiful and mysterious Sun Horse**,
>   which local legends identify as **living in Forgotten Valley in the
>   mountains.**
>
> Of course, Mark and Giselle decide that they are going to find and
>   bring home Giselle's father. Their adventures include making friends
>   with a bat (whom Giselle is surprised to find she can communicate with
>   telepathically), **meeting the Marsh Witch** who takes care of the swans
>   and runs around the marsh on her stilts, and asking for assistance
>   from the local Indian tribe.
>
> The Marsh Witch is particularly fun--she uses cobwebs and captured
>   dreams to make sky ropes which can lasso clouds. She then climbs the
>   ropes and rides the clouds to see what is going on in the valley.
>   Although she looks scary in the beginning, the children discover that
>   she is really a caring woman and a great ally.

- The father of one of the main characters has disappeared:

  > Her father has mysteriously gone missing....
- There is a Sun Horse:

  > ...the beautiful and mysterious Sun Horse....
- And a witch:

  > ...meeting the Marsh Witch who takes care of the swans
  >   and runs around the marsh on her stilts.
- There is a hidden magical land in the mountains:

  > ...living in Forgotten Valley in the
  >   mountains.
- And of course, there are two children, a boy and a girl. They aren't siblings, though, and the boy lives with his aunt and uncle, not his mother.

There aren't any soldiers mentioned in anything I saw, but there are is a Native Canadian man whom I believe might guard the Sun Horse.

---

**More information**

[There are characters](http://www.abebooks.com/book-search/author/catherine-anthony-clark/) called the Flame Lighter Woman and the Bat:

> There they meet strange people like the Flame Lighter Woman and the
>   Bat, and have many adventures.

The main antagonist of the story [appears to be](http://boards.ancestry.com/topics.obits/65769/mb.ashx) the Thunderbird:

> The children's search leads them to the domain of the Thunderbird, an
>   evil creature whose lofty perch affords it considerable protection and
>   power over creatures below. The children overcome their fears and
>   eventually undertake the dangerous climb to the Thunderbird's nest.
>   They are thus able to rescue Giselle's father.

More details, along with a few excerpts, are also given in [this](https://canlit.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/CL078-Full-Issue.pdf) academic work.